# How store text property of controls for winform in database or any other type to make it more dynamic?

Tags: database, winforms, dynamic

How store text property of controls for winform in database or any other type to make it more dynamic?
Eg.

Label.Text

Form.Text

I want to achieve it using Windows Form and SQL Server as database or XML file or any other option.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  What database?  Which language?

Comment: Jim, I want to make text of the control dynamic. I mean to say I want to have the functionality to change the text of the labels in Form 1 from the Form 2 so that my client can set names of the labels as per their requirement @JimBuckleyBarret

Comment: What database?  What language?  We can't give you examples without knowing this.

Comment: I want to do this in Windows Form using C# and SQL Server as database @JimBuckleyBarret Sorry I forgot to mention.

Comment: Read about databinding. it's too broad for stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi, Zohar is correct this is just to open.  I'm surprised a mentor hasn't jumped all over it.  What you need to do is do a google search for reading data from MS Server using C# and for writing to MS Server using C#.  You'll find something like this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16563514/retrieving-data-from-sql-server-2008r2-using-winforms.  Once you try it and you have a specific question come back and we'll help more.